# How make React admin's <SimpleFormIterator> behave as a stack on item addition (add item on top)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, react-final-form

I have an item with a nested list of items. I can edit these nested items individually using a *<SimpleFormIterator>* mixed with a *<FormDataConsumer>*. The issue is that when i insert a new item in the list, it becomes the last item. I would like it to be the first, and shift every other item down a slot.

Maybe something like using a custom  with an **addOnTop** callback could help? But I don't see a way to make it work without rewriting the whole component from scratch.

```
<SimpleFormIterator
     addButton={<ListAddButton onClick={addOnTop??} />}
     removeButton={<ListRemoveButton />}
>
...
</SimpleFormIterator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I think I managed to solve doing something like this:

```
const form = useForm();
    const getData = useCallback(() => {
        const emptyArticle = {
            URL: "",
            title: "",
            image: "",
            eyelet: "",
            topic: "",
        };
        const { articles } = form.getState().values;
        if (!articles) return [emptyArticle];
        articles.pop();
        articles.unshift(emptyArticle);
        return articles;
}, [form]);

<SimpleFormIterator
    addButton={
        <ListAddButton onClick={() => form.change("articles", getData())} />
  }
    removeButton={<ListRemoveButton />}
    TransitionProps={{
        enter: false,
        exit: false,
        addEndListener: () => {},
    }}
>
<SimpleFormIterator/>
```

I'm not sure it is the best approach, but it seems to work, although there is currently a [bug with this component](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/7385) that forces the use of *"emptyArticle"* instead of simply pushing *"undefined"*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try with unshift(). Here is the link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift